# Is there any API to calculate total price from given number of quantities in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I am using stripe graduated pricing model. and i need to show total price calculated when user selects number of products in realtime. i want to avoid price calculations from frontend.
are there any API from stripe available that can calculate total price?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API that you can use to retrieve a total estimated price based on tiered usage. Once solution would be to store the tiering model in your own system and make the calculations there.

Another option would be to retrieve the Price and expand the tier information and to use the values there to estimate usage based on user input.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-tiers